# Where to find the frequency of 3-grams?

Tags: n-gram

Where can I get a dataset of the frequency of 3 letter combinations ([3-grams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram))? When I try to look for 3-grams and other n-grams online, it usually shows me combinations of 3 *words*, not letters.

(I could generate my own, of course, but I'm wondering if there is a ready to use data-set of them.)

Comment: "frequency of 3 letter combinations"? Frequency *in what*?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Oh sorry, the English language.